# sharing a :memory: database between different threads in python using sqlite3 package

Tags: python, sqlite, python-multithreading

I would like to create a :memory: database in python and access it from different threads.
Essentially something like:

```
class T(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
        # do stuff with the database

for i in xrange(N):
    T().start()
```

and have all the connections referring to the same database.

I am aware of passing `check_same_thread=True` to the connect function and sharing the 
connection between threads but would like to avoid doing that if possible. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: corrected a typo. I originally said "have all the connections referring to the same thread" substituting thread for database.

Comment: Can you please describe the scenario for which this is needed? May be there are other options rather than using sqlite from multiple threads?

Comment: @Muhammad Alkarouri I needed it for unit testing a multi threaded database application. If a file is used (as it would be in actual application) then I can open multiple connections to if just fine. I ended up wrapping the database logic in one thread that uses the consumer pattern and returns deferreds that it fills when it gets to the request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without hacking sqlite3 library itself you cannot reuse `:memory:` database, because it's guaranteed to be exclusive and private for every connection. To hack access to it, look closer at `src/pager.c` in sqlite3 distribution (not Python module distribution). Maybe, most convenient way to implement this would be make `:memory:00`, `:memory:something`, `:memory:okay_hai` etc. aliases to address different `pPager->memDb` pointers through some simple C-side mapping.

Comment: Hi there, any new information on this almost 4 years later? Is it still not possible with current sqlite3 in Python?

Comment: @compostus, it's now possible with specifying database URI, refer to this http://www.sqlite.org/uri.html, look for `mode=memory` and `cache=shared`.

Comment: @compostus, see my new answer to this question.

Answer (score 40):

SQLite had improved over last 4 years, so now shared in-memory databases are possible. Check the following code:

```
import sqlite3

foobar_uri = 'file:foobar_database?mode=memory&cache=shared'
not_really_foobar_uri = 'file:not_really_foobar?mode=memory&cache=shared'

# connect to databases in no particular order
db2 = sqlite3.connect(foobar_uri, uri=True)
db_lol = sqlite3.connect(not_really_foobar_uri, uri=True)
db1 = sqlite3.connect(foobar_uri, uri=True)

# create cursor as db2
cur2 = db2.cursor()

# create table as db2
db2.execute('CREATE TABLE foo (NUMBER bar)')

# insert values as db1
db1.execute('INSERT INTO foo VALUES (42)')
db1.commit()

# and fetch them from db2 through cur2
cur2.execute('SELECT * FROM foo')
print(cur2.fetchone()[0])  # 42

# test that db_lol is not shared with db1 and db2
try:
    db_lol.cursor().execute('SELECT * FROM foo')
except sqlite3.OperationalError as exc:
    print(exc)  # just as expected
```

Database accesses are entangled intentionally, to show that two connections to the in-memory database with the same name are the same from SQLite's point of view.

References:

1. [SQLite URIs](http://www.sqlite.org/uri.html)
2. [SQLite shared cache](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html)

---

Unfortunately, connection by URI is only available since Python 3.4. However, if you have Python 2.6 or later (but not Python 3), builtin `sqlite3` module is still capable of importing APSW connections, which can be used to achieve same effect. Here goes the drop-in `sqlite3` module replacement:

```
from sqlite3 import *
from sqlite3 import connect as _connect
from apsw import Connection as _ApswConnection
from apsw import SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE as _SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE
from apsw import SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE as _SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE
from apsw import SQLITE_OPEN_URI as _SQLITE_OPEN_URI

# APSW and pysqlite use different instances of sqlite3 library, so initializing
# APSW won't help pysqlite. Because pysqlite does not expose any way to
# explicitly call sqlite3_initialize(), here goes an ugly hack. This only has
# to be done once per process.
_connect(':memory:').close()

def connect(database, timeout=5.0, detect_types=0, isolation_level=None,
            check_same_thread=True, factory=Connection, cached_statements=100,
            uri=False):
    flags = _SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | _SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE

    if uri:
        flags |= _SQLITE_OPEN_URI

    db = _ApswConnection(database, flags, None, cached_statements)
    conn = _connect(db, timeout, detect_types, isolation_level, 
                    check_same_thread, factory, cached_statements)

    return conn
```

Comment: thanx a lot! I was looking at python 3.3 docs, so i overlooked the `uri` option of `sqlite3.connect()`, which is only **available since Python 3.4**.

Comment: what is the best alternative (if any) for anyone still on Python 2.7?

Comment: unfortunately this is causing my python to crash....will be updating to Python 3 unless you have another suggestion for an in-memory db that i can access from different threads

Comment: @baconwichsand if it crashes, please, triple check you had not thrown out `_connect(':memory:').close()` line — it is critically important to do a connection with pysqlite once, because it will call `sqlite3_initialize()` implicitly. Without this line, sqlite instance of pysqlite will have no mutexes created and will die when trying to lock on connection.

Comment: @baconwichsand if it will still crash, please tell your OS and exact Python version, and I will update an answer to reflect your case.

Comment: I actually just upgraded to 3.4!

Comment: So i got this working, but am getting really weird behavior when copying DB from disk into memory, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35317751/loading-sqlite-db-into-memory-with-shared-cache-only-works-with-pdb-set-trace