# 2 shells 1 cup. Sharing a queue between 2 Python scripts on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, node.js, linux, python-2.7, sqlite

I have 2 Python scripts on a Raspberry Pi, 1 runs in a background shell emptying a queue, the other runs in the foreground adding user inputs to the queue. I've build a version where the queue is stored as a SQLite database and in order to make this work each script has to connect to the database before each operation and disconnect afterwards which avoids locking conflict but slows the process down significantly. This overhead means I am actually able to hammer the inputs fast enough to *confuse* the script and make it miss/ignore some inputs. **Is a single SQLite datbase the fastest method for storing my shared queue or is there some faster alternative (possibly one that uses RAM instead of writing to disk) that both scripts can access quicker?**

*(Note: I'm open to drastic suggestions like switching language to NodeJS)*

I didn't post the code because it's more a question of appropriate technology for the job but if you want to see my current repo it's at https://github.com/martinjoiner/bookfetch-scanner-python

Comment: Why do you need to close and reopen the collection? SQLite don't support concurrent solutions? A less radical solution may be to change for a DB that does. MongoDB for example.

Comment: There are a lot of messaging solutions that would seem to be better for IPC messaging (e.g., ZeroMQ, or a messaging server like redis or rabbitmq, etc)

Comment: why use an SQLite database in the first place? Are you allowing queries or something?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Traditionally I am a LAMP stack web developer. When I am building 2 things that share data the first thing I think of is a database. Why? What non-database technologies exist in the Linux environment that I could leverage?

Comment: Point taken. How about not checking them instantly in one-by-one, but collecting them (appending the codes to a list in RAM or smthg) and doing it collectively when the "hammering" stops. Like `if 30 sec passed from the last hammering: INSERT...` in pseudocode?