# Python on Raspberry Pi user input inside infinite loop misses inputs when hit with many

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-2.x

I have a very basic *parrot* script written in Python that simply prompts for a user input and prints it back inside an infinite loop. The Raspberry Pi has a USB barcode scanner attached for the input.

```
while True:
    barcode = raw_input("Scan barcode: ")
    print "Barcode scanned: " + barcode
```

When you scan at a "normal" speed it works reliably and the command output looks like this:

```
Scan barcode: 9780465031467
Barcode scanned: 9780465031467
Scan barcode: 9780007505142
Barcode scanned: 9780007505142
```

But when you really hammer it with many scans in close succession it is possible to make it miss inputs and the command output looks like this:

```
Scan barcode: 9780141049113
Barcode scanned: 9780141049113
Scan barcode: 9780465031467
Barcode scanned: 9780465031467
Scan barcode: 9780007505142
9780571273188
Barcode scanned: 9780571273188
```

Notice how `9780007505142` was input but never printed back. It got *lost* in the confusion.

See a video demonstration of my test at: https://youtu.be/kdsfdKFhC1M

My question: **Is this an inevitability of using a low powered device like a Pi? Will it always be true that a user with a barcode scanner will be able to *out-run* the hardware's ability to keep up?**

Comment: Java you tried another language? -see what I did there-?

Comment: @Jay No. Do you think there's a real chance that if I run the test in Java I won't be able to out-run it?

Comment: I would say try it for testing purposes. Perhaps its a slow library, perhaps a slow language, perhaps the cpu just cant keepup. I will say that if you use c/c++/java you will have better performance for sure. The problem with c/c++ is that its hard to setup and you might not find the library you are looking for. Java is easier with easier setup with guaranteed performance gains.

Comment: What about reading directly from [`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin)?

Comment: After watching the video: Does `print "Barcode scanned: [%s]" % barcode` print a multi-line output, i.e. both barcodes inside the single bracket? If so, all you'd have to do is split the data...

Comment: @Tomalak No it still misses one of the scans :-(

Comment: Reading straight from the device would be the next step. The characters *obviously* are being recognized, otherwise they would not be on screen, would they. Therefore something's fishy with `raw_input()`

Answer (score 2):

You should probably read from `stdin` directly using code similar to the following:

```
import os
import sys
import select

stdin_fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
try:
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write("Scan barcode: ")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        r_list = [stdin_fd]
        w_list = list()
        x_list = list()
        r_list, w_list, x_list = select.select(r_list, w_list, x_list)
        if stdin_fd in r_list:
            result = os.read(stdin_fd, 1024)
            result = result.rstrip()
            result = [line.rstrip() for line in result.split('\n')]
            for line in result:
                print "Barcode scanned: %s" % line
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Keyboard interrupt"
```

This code should handle the case that multiple lines are read at once. The `read` buffer size is arbitrary and you might have to change it depending on how much data you need to handle.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late, but after a closer look at the raw_input() [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) I think it is pretty plain that raw_input is not designed to handle multi-line inputs. When it encounters a multi-line input it seems to only read the last line. (as demonstrated by your test). So my question is, how is raw_input getting a multi-line input in the first place? is the delay caused by the python program not being able to process the raw_input fast enough? Or is the delay inside the USB scanner/driver, and as a result it outputs two numbers instantaneously causing raw_input to process the last line without giving it an opportunity to process the first?