# Peewee Sqlite share in memory database

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, peewee, in-memory-database

Reading this post I learnt that is possible to have shared in-memory database across thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24708173/7754093

Using sqlite python package I could do this:

```
sqlite3.connect('file:foobar_database?mode=memory&cache=shared', uri=True)
```

How can this be done in Peewee? I can't find any documentation that describes it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `sqlite3` module can successfully connect to a shared in-memory database, then the following will work:

```
from peewee import *
sqlite_db = SqliteDatabase('file:foobar_database?mode=memory&cache=shared')
```